# Field customisation for nested and inherited models in Pydantic

Tags: python, validation, python-typing, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I've thoroughly searched for an answer for this query, with little avail.

Using pydantic, the `ge=0` validation of `item_main` in the following example proceeds without a hitch, would be expected (as per instructions: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customisation):

```
class SubCls(BaseModel):
    item_sub: float = Field(...)

class MainCls(BaseModel):
    item_main1: float = Field(...)
    item_main2: SubCls

    class Config:
        fields = {'item_main1': {'ge': 0}}
```

However, the `ge=0` validation of nested `item_sub` in the following example does not work:

```
class SubCls(BaseModel):
    item_sub: float = Field(...)

class MainCls(BaseModel):
    item_main1: float = Field(...)
    item_main2: SubCls

    class Config:
        fields = {'item_main2': {"item_sub":{'ge': 0}}}
```

Neither does it when `SubCl` is inherited by `MainCls`:

```
class SubCls(BaseModel):
    item_sub: float = Field(...)

class MainCls(SubCls):
    item_main1: float = Field(...)

    class Config:
        fields = {"item_sub":{'ge': 0}}
```

I am wondering how I can best apply field customisation to nested models. Of course, the most elegant way to do it is to create a new `SubCls` models, with the validation information added, but in my use case this would lead to a rather excessive number of models.
I'd be grateful for any help.

This query has been cross-posted on pydantic's github forum: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/discussions/3400.

Comment: I think that if you have different validation rules for what seems to be a single model you actually have different models. How many models would you have to create? Why is it an excessive number?

Comment: I would like to use the same schemas for many different functions, but many of these functions have different `Field` parameter arguments (such as different `ge`, `gt`, `le`, `lt`, `title` and `description`). Of course I could also validate the input within the functions, but that somewhat defeats the purpose of pydantic validation. I was hoping to use common models/schemas, but with different `class Config` options to diversify the model validations. It would save on much duplication.

Comment: @Svencken the question is unclear, but sounds like you might want a metaclass for this

Comment: @rv.kvetch, thanks, I will look into this. Apologies if the question is unclear, happy to answer any questions about it to help clarify.

Comment: Probably the question is outdated, but can't you add a class Config to the SubCls?