# Changing pydantic model Field() arguments with class variables for Fastapi

Tags: python, validation, subclass, fastapi, pydantic

I'm a little new to tinkering with class inheritance in python, particularly when it comes down to using ****class attributes****. In this case I am using a **class attribute** to change an argument in pydantic's `Field()` function. This wouldn't be too hard to do if my class contained it's own constructor, however, my class `User1` is inheriting this from pydantic's `BaseModel`.
The idea is that I would like to be able to change the **class attribute** prior to creating the instance.

Please see some example code below:

```
from pydantic import Basemodel, Field   

class User1(BaseModel):
    _set_ge = None # create class attribute
    item: float = Field(..., ge=_set_ge)

    # avoid overriding BaseModel's __init__
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
User1._set_ge = 0 # setting the class attribute to a new value
instance = User1(item=-1)
print(instance) # item=-1.0
```

When creating the instance using `instance = User1(item=-1)` I would expect a validation error to be thrown, but it instead passes validation and simply returns the `item` value.

If I had my own constructor there would be little issue in changing the `_set_ge`, but as `User1` inheriting this constructor from `BaseModel`, things are a little more complicated.

The eventual aim is to add this class to a `fastapi` endpoint as follows:

```
from fastapi import Fastapi
from schemas import User1    

class NewUser1(User1):
      pass

NewUser1._set_ge = 0    

@app.post("/")
def endpoint(request: NewUser1):
    return User1.item
```

To reduce code duplication, I aimed to use this method to easily change `Field()` arguments. If there is a better way, I'd be glad to consider that too.

This question is quite closely related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911738/field-customisation-for-nested-and-inherited-models-in-pydantic) unanswered one.

Comment: Why don't you use a [validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/)? As far as I know, `ge` (and others) is designed to be used with fixed values.

Comment: I thought about this and it perhaps might indeed be the best solution. I've reused custom validators for more complex validations. However, I was hoping to rely on pydantic's built-in validation methods as much as I could, while simultaneously learning a bit more about using class attributes with pydantic models (and @dataclass, which I assume would have similar behaviour). Furthermore, down the road I may want to make the `title` and `description` arguments of `Field()` customisable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the `@validator` proposal by @hernán-alarcón is probably the best way to do this. For example:

```
from pydantic import Basemodel, Field, NumberNotGeError
from typing import ClassVar   

class User(BaseModel):
    _set_ge = ClassVar[float] # added the ClassVar typing to make clearer, but the underscore should be sufficient
    item: float = Field(...)

    @validator('item')
    def limits(cls, v):
        limit_number = cls._set_ge
        if v >= limit_number:
            return v
        else:
            raise NumberNotGeError(limit_value=limit_number)
        
    
class User1(User)
     _set_ge = 0 # setting the class attribute to a new value

instance = User1(item=-1) # raises the error
```

Comment: Good answer - Just don't forget to import validator from pydantic as well!